# Azure web app - Additional deployment slots affect production slot?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I am using Azure app service for hosting my web application. I have three slots namely 1. Development, 2.Staging , 3.Production.

I usually go with publishing my website into Development slot and I will swap to Staging and Production.

Whether running additional two slots will affect my production slot performance? And will be billed separately?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As described in the Azure pricing page, specific tiers of Azure App Services contain a number of staging environments (deployment slots). These are included in the app service plan, whether you use them or not. Cost is based on tier and number of instances, not number of slots.

All resources within an App Service plan share the same resources (e.g. if you launch many web apps in the same App Service plan, they all share the same instances). All deployment slots for a given web app reside within the same App Service plan.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification